# Ejabberd External Authentication : extauth script has exitted abruptly with reason 'normal'

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, quickblox

I'm trying to enable external authentication in my Ejabberd installation.  I keep receiving following error message.

**extauth script has exitted abruptly with reason 'normal'**

My ejabberd version is 2.1.13.

Tried with following configurations,

1.{auth_method, external}. 
{extauth_program,"php /tmp/test.php"}.

2.{auth_method, external}. 
{extauth_program,"/tmp/test.php"}.

3 {auth_method, external}.
%%{extauth_program,"/tmp/test.php"}.

All the above configuration returns same error.

Answer (score 0):

What is your test.php script?,  are you sure it is working?.  Maybe it is just terminating normally as the error says. 
The auth script is supposed to not terminate,  just keep running reading from stdin.  There is an example you could use as guide here
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/examples/extauth/check_pass_null.pl

Comment: I executed the script manually from command line as root user and ejabberd user, it executes and doesn't seem to be throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Spent 1 day trying to get work ejabberd authorization.
Problem basicly appears in blocking the process while reading from stdin. It is being kept blocked at the end of request string until client disconnects because of timeout.
Here is a solution for non-block symbol by symbol reading from descriptor:

```
function non_block_read($fd, &$data) {
    $read = array($fd);
    $write = array();
    $except = array();
    $result = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0);
    if($result === false) {
                throw new Exception('stream_select failed');
        }
    if($result === 0) return false;
    $data.= stream_get_line($fd, 1);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the daemon code also to make lifetime reading cycle.

```
$fh  = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
$fhout  = fopen("php://stdout", 'w');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user,$pass);
if(!$fh){
    die("Cannot open STDIN\n");
}
$aStr='';
$collect=false;
do {
        if (!non_block_read($fh,$aStr)) {
                if (strlen($aStr) > 0) {
                       $toAuth = substr(trim($aStr),1);
                       checkAuth($toAuth,$pdo,$fhout);
                       $aStr='';
                }
                else sleep (1);
        }
}
while (true);
```

Some explaination: checkAuth - any function that implements 'auth' and 'isuser' handlers.
sleep(1) - simple way to escape CPU load.
First symbol - service symbol that prepends the message and it differs from client to client, so I just cut it.
Here is reply code. Reply - true | false values.

```
$message =  @pack("nn", 2, $result);
fwrite($stdout, $message);
flush();
```

Enjoy.